# How To Toggle Between Celsius and Fahrenheit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have created a toggle button to switch between Celsius and Fahrenheit for my weather application. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to get it to work with my current code setup.

Up to this point, I've tried using the jQuery toggle method. But, I don't know how that would work with my code.

What other solutions can I try to solve this issue?

Here is some minimal code used to formulate this problem. I hope this helps.

HTML:

```
 <section>
    <div id="date"></div>
    <div class="weather">
      <div id="cityName"></div>
      <img src="" id="icon">
      <div id="description"></div>
      <div id="temp"></div>
    </div>
      <div class="switchBtn">
        <button class="switch" onclick="cfSwitch()">Celsius (°C ) / Fahrenheit (°F)</button>
      </div>
  </section>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getWeather( cityID ) {
  var key = '{api key}';
  fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=' + cityID+ '&appid=' + key)  
  .then(function(resp) { return resp.json() }) // Convert data to json
  .then(function(data) {
    drawWeather(data);
  })
  .catch(function() {
    // catch any errors
  });
}

window.onload = function() {
  getWeather( 6167865 );
}

function drawWeather( d ) {
  var celsius = Math.round(parseFloat(d.main.temp)-273.15);
  var fahrenheit = Math.round(((parseFloat(d.main.temp)-273.15)*1.8)+32); 

  document.getElementById('cityName').innerHTML = d.name;
  document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = d.weather[0].description;
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = fahrenheit + '&deg;F';
  document.getElementById('icon').src = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+d.weather[0].icon+".png";
 }
```

Comment: If this is really a React app you're violating several basic principles, such as not directly modifying the DOM. I don't see any evidence that it is, though. Why is it tagged?

Comment: Don't share your appid!!!

Comment: Why don't we see a function named `cfSwitch`?

Comment: Just put both on your page at the same time inside your temperature div with `<span class="celcius">blah</span><span class="fahrenheit">blah</span>` with your site CSS set to hide one and show the other, and only make your JS toggle your CSS classes?

Comment: @trincot Thanks for the heads up. If you don't mind me asking, why shouldn't I share my appid? Is it because of privacy concerns? Or is it due to something else? I am fairly new to programming, so I want to learn as much as possible. Your feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By sharing your app id, you risk that several people will use it to actually make calls, and this can quickly reach the call limit. openweathermap will contact *you* about this abuse, because it was a key assigned to you personally. See [appid](https://openweathermap.org/appid)

Comment: @trincot noted. I will consider that for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need some way to know wether you are showing C of F beforehand, and the temperature, to know to what measure to convert and to what.

You can store that variable and the temperature as global variables in your js file; for instance initialise `tempMode` in Celsius and `currentTemperature` to 0 and then assigning to it before/during your `drawWeather` function. Then have the `cfSwitch()` function to grab both, do the conversion and assign it again to the `temp` id. `cfSwitch()` would need to change from C to F or F to C depending on the `tempMode` variable, and switch it accordingly (if you go from Celsius to Fahrenheit, change it to Fahrenheit after doing the conversion, and so on)

Another solution would be to store the temperatures (maybe in an object, like `TEMPERATURES = { CELSIUS: c_temp, FAHRENHEIT: f_temp }`, store to them in your initial calls all the different ones and have `cfSwitch` toggle between them.

Another thing from the openWeather docs, you are able to request either Fahrenheit or Celsius using the `mode` query param, so you don't have to convert Kelvins initially.

```
Temperature is available in Fahrenheit, Celsius and Kelvin units.
For temperature in Fahrenheit use units=imperial
For temperature in Celsius use units=metric
Temperature in Kelvin is used by default, no need to use units parameter in API call
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an object for reference.

```
let weather = {
    city: 6167865,
    description: '',
    celcius: undefined,
    fahrenheit: undefined,
    temp: undefined,
    icon: undefined
};

function switchTemp() {
    let sign = 'F';
    if (weather.temp === weather.celcius) weather.temp = weather.fahrenheit;
    else {
        weather.temp = weather.celcius;
        sign = 'C';
    }
    document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = weather.temp + '&deg;' + sign;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used object to toggle the temperature button

````
let tempObject;

//class Temp
class Temp{
  constructor(temp){
    this.temp = temp;
  }
}
//convet celcius to fahrenheit
const ctof = function (num) {
    let convertedNum = (Math.round(((parseInt(num) * 9 / 5) + 32) * 10) / 10);
    return convertedNum;
}

function addTempToClass(num){
  //add the Temp Value gotten from getTemp() to object 
  tempObject = new Temp(num);
  
  //give your button that toggles the temperature an id with value gotten from object property temp
  tempbtn.setAttribute("id", `${tempObject.temp}`)
}

//function that toggles button
function toggleTemp(num){
  //get variable returned from an assign it to fahrenheit variable
  let fahrenheitNum = ctof(num);

  //if statement to toggle temp property in TempObject
  if(tempObject.temp == num){
    tempObject.temp = fahrenheitNum;
  }else{
    tempObject.temp = num;
  }
}

async function getTemp(){
  //your final temperature value
  let temp; 
  //fetch temp promise and convert to a value
  
  //pass final value to addTemptToClass function
  addTempToClass(temp)
}
//button
tempbtn.addEventListener("click", (e){
                         //pass your id value gotten from tempbtn which we assigned in addTempToClass to toggleTemp()
                         toggleTemp(e.target.id);
                         })
getTemp();```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).